# popToRootViewControllerAnimated toolbar not correctly updating

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITabBarController whose tabs are UINavigationController.  I have initialized each navigationController by:

```
 iPhoneApp *appDelegate = (iPhoneApp *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [appDelegate.navigationController2 initWithRootViewController:countryController];
```

I then drill down the navigationController with:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

I want to pop to the root of my navigationController(s) when the user clicks on a tabBar tab.

```
 [delegate.navigationController2 popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

This seems to work great when I only pushViewController one level, but fails when I drill down multiple levels in my navigationController.  What happens is that it pops to root but doesn't contain my Root's backbutton or title:

```
 self.navigationItem.title = @"My title";
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

 UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                         target:self
                                                     action:@selector(handleBack:)];
```

if I don't poptoroot and just use the navigationControlls back button, everything works correctly.

I logged my viewControllers before and after i poptoroot

before:
    MainCountryController: 0x3d53650,
    IndividualCountryMfgViewController: 0x3d67d50,
    IndividualCountryProductViewController: 0x3d60870

after:
    MainCountryController: 0x3d53650

it's the right view, but wrong toolbar title and backbutton.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by disconnecting my navigation controllers from IB an just creating them programatically.